# TypeError: Menus.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm shucked at his error `TypeError: Menus.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` any one please help me to solve his error

main file: -->

```
from tkinter import *
from meanu_items import *


def main():
    windows = Tk()
    windows.title("NotePad")
    windows.minsize(width=60, height=80)
    windows.config()
    # Create place to write a text
    text = Text(windows)
    text.focus()
    text.grid(pady=0.5, padx=10)

    # Creating Scale
    scroll = Scrollbar(windows, orient=VERTICAL, )
    scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS + SE)
    text.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    scroll.config(command=text.yview)

    menu = Menus(windows)

    windows.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

meanu_items file: -->

```
 from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

SIDE_R = RIGHT


class Menus(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__()
        self.filetypes = (
            ('text files', '*.txt'),
            ('All files', '*.*'))
        self.text = Text()
        self.menubar()

    def menubar(self):
        # Menu bar

        # # File
        menubar = Menu(self)

        file = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

        file.add_command(label="New")
        file.add_command(label="Open", command=self.opens)
        file.add_command(label="Save")
        file.add_command(label="close")

        file.add_separator()

        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

        # # Edit

        edit = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

        edit.add_command(label="Copy")
        edit.add_command(label="Paste")
        edit.add_command(label="Cute")
        edit.add_command(label="Delete")
        edit.add_command(label="Select All")

        menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit)

        # # Help
        helps = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        helps.add_command(label="About")
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)

    def opens(self):
        dlg = filedialog.Open(self, filetypes=self.filetypes)
        fl = dlg.show()

        if fl != '':
            text = self.readFile(fl)
            self.text.insert(END, text)
```

some minor error are also there in above file(meanU_items):-->

```
Expected type 'Menu', got '(args: tuple[Any, ...], kwds: dict[str, Any]) -> None' instead : 50
Unresolved attribute reference 'readFile' for class 'Menus' :57
```

Comment: Your code has: 'menu = Menus(windows)', but you don't have a windows parameter in the Menus class.

Comment: if I remove windows from: 'menu = Menus(windows)', but def menubr() not working, sir, can you help me to correct it or what should I make it to run

Comment: You just create `menubar` without showing it using `.config(menu=menubar)`.  Note that you can only show `menubar` in a window (i.e. `Tk` or `Toplevel`), not in a frame.  Also avoid using same variable name on both a variable and a function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Menu class is asking 'self'

```
class Menus(Frame):

def __init__(self):
```

but instead of a Menus object you gave it a window object. Write this in init:

```
class Menus(Frame):

def __init__(self, windows):
```

and create Menus object like this:-

```
menu = Menus(menus_items.Menus, windows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to tell, but perhaps you meant to pass in the `windows` parameter to pass it onto the `Frame` super class:

```py
class Menus(Frame):

    def __init__(self, windows):
        super().__init__(windows)
        ...
```

Comment: It should be `Frame.__init__(self, windows)` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use `super()` ... fixing ...